# Tier 4 UK student general visa cap

Tags: visa, student-visa

I am of Ukrainian nationality.

So I have studied in the UK for 5 years now almost (total of 7 years that I have been in UK, 2 years of college education does not count towards tier 4 cap I believe, otherwise I wouldn't get my current student visa). Starting my second postgrad this September. I have a bachelor's and now two masters degrees. My intention is to study another bachelor's at Cambridge/Oxford, would I be able to obtain a student visa?

If not, are there any other ways which would enable me to stay and study at the above mentioned?

Comment: Just because I'm curious... I studied in the UK for 5 years for a MPhys, and it was *very expensive*. How in the world can you afford to study a second bachelors on top of the first + 2 masters, especially when they keep raising costs? Unless you're getting funded for the Masters, which means you must be very good!

Comment: I did get two scholarships, but they only covered a fraction of the cost of the programme. Having rich parents helps...

Comment: Wow, well good for you for doing what you want to do! I think I'll be paying my loans off until I'm well past middle age, but in my situation it was definitely worth it because it pointed me toward a new career path. However I still hold the opinion that UK international fees are no less than predatory, especially since they've been increasing every single year...

Comment: Thanks. But it does not seem likely that I will be studying there... Because of the visa.. I agree with you. My degree, if by some miracle I will indeed obtain a visa, will be in mathematics and I will be doing awesome stuff like black holes, quantum field theory and general relativity in the final year, which would be a dream. But you have already done cosmology and astrophysics! In my view there is nothing more interesting in this world than that :) So who cares about loans if you are already living a dream!

Comment: Have you thought about another country? I had originally intended to stay in the UK and I had several PhD offers there, but I am not rich and couldn't afford 20k tuition plus living expenses for 3 more years. I ended up moving to France where the education is the same price (cheap as chips) for everyone. Given the anti-immigrant sentiment in the UK and the maybe-Brexit, I'm very happy with the move.

And yes, cosmology is actually my favourite thing in the world. It's sort of what I work in now (although on the instrumentation side of things). I can send you some slides if you want!

Comment: That would be so cool. We need to connect, how can we share our e-mails safely, if you are up for that? Well, the problem of moving from UK is that I have been here for 7 years now, and if I stay for 3 more, I will get the permanent residence here, which is quite good. I was thinking about Harvard and MIT for maths also, but I would need to sit SATs and I am not sure I have time to apply for those unis now. Plus, Harvard is even more expensive than Cambridge.